# Why iptables is flowing?

Tags: debian, iptables, dns

I have iptables configuration:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And after, trying this:

```
user@debian:~$ host yahoo.com
../../../../lib/isc/unix/net.c:581: sendmsg() failed: Operation not permitted
yahoo.com has address 98.138.219.232
yahoo.com has address 72.30.35.9
yahoo.com has address 72.30.35.10
yahoo.com has address 98.137.246.7
yahoo.com has address 98.137.246.8
yahoo.com has address 98.138.219.231
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:c:1023::5
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:44:41d::3
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:44:41d::4
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:58:1836::10
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:58:1836::11
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:c:1023::4
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
```

How? I thought, it was "cache", and try some others domains. They all been resolved.

"Ok, maybe it's some local DNS cache" - turn off internet from machine. Ok didn't resolve.

How? Why?

Comment: If you think your edit answers your question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**

I didn't notice that magic:

```
yahoo.com has address 98.138.219.231
yahoo.com has IPv6 address 2001:4998:c:1023::5
```

And thus, i have to setup rules for "ip6tables":

```
# ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
# ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
# ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
```

and my result:

```
../../../../lib/isc/unix/net.c:581: sendmsg() failed: Operation not permitted
../../../../lib/isc/unix/net.c:581: sendmsg() failed: Operation not permitted
;; connection timed out ; no servers could be reached
```

P.S. If I remembered about "tcpdump", then problem solved faster.